# Создание парсера в C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, парсер, firemonkey

Сообщение Test выводит. А вот сам текст не выводит. Что делать? Строка выглядит так:

```
<div class="head_2"> Сервер 4<br>mTSG@72_Touch_Me_v4 </div>
```

Сам код:

```
AnsiString One=IdHTTP1->Get("http://www.xn--c1adahg2atfb8hee9d.xn--p1ai/");

    String N,K;

    N="<div class=\"head_2\"> Сервер 4<br />";
    K="</div>";

    int p,p2;

     while (One.Pos(N)&&One.Pos(K)) {


      if (p == 0 && p2 == 0) break;

    p=One.Pos(N);
    p2=One.Pos(K);
    AnsiString Value="None";
    Value=One.SubString(p,p2-p);
    if (p!=0&&p2!=0) Memo1->Lines->Add(Value+"Test");

     int sPos = One.Pos(N);
      int ePos = One.Pos(K);
      if (sPos == 0 && ePos == 0) break;
      if (sPos != 0) One.Delete(sPos,1);
      if (ePos != 0) One.Delete(ePos,1);
    }
    ShowMessage("Compite");
```

Взял готовый код тут же на КИберфоруме. Помогите с проблемой, либо киньте нормальный парсер :c

Comment: _Что делать?_ - проверить код на наличие ошибок. Отладку никто не отменял.

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка ответа от вебсервера может не совпадать с кодировкой которую представляет AnsiString.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.